# I am coding to save & print prime numbers from the range of 1 ... 10 in 2 dimensional array.

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here is my code. The output is 7 7 7 7 in a single row instead of 2 3 5 7 in two rows. Kindly point out mistakes.

```
int [][] array = new int [2][2];
int N =10;
    for (int num = 2; num <= N; num++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){ 
                for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++){ 
                    if(isprime(num)){
                        array[i][j] = num;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
            System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
}
private static boolean isprime(int number) {
    for (int i = 2; i < number; i++) {
        if(number % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
}
return true;
```

Comment: why are you using 2d array?

Comment: did you try to debug?

Comment: @Azodious raised a valid point, if some effort was made please show us what you're not sure about :)

Comment: @KarthikT : nothing specific, just learning if I could do it.

Comment: @user2575149 unnecessary complexity, makes it harder to see your problem, which by the way is explained in my answer

Comment: @Karthik T: I am beginner in coding and was trying to create modified problems to solve. Solution by Malav depicts that you are very correct that I was creating complex problems for myself. Better to avoid it.

Comment: Ok...last question... why    [   arr[index] = prime; index++;   ]             not working.

Answer (score 0):

It is printed in one line because you are missing `{}` after for statement.
Use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
        System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

All values are 7 because you use 3 loops when you shouldn't.
When you loop over numbers 0 to 10, you iterate over all cells and update it if it is prime. The result is that all values are 7 because it is the last prime between 0 to 10.

You should rethink your logic. One solution is to loop over all numbers and check if one is prime, put it in the next empty cell (1D array should be enough).

Answer (score 0):

Your 2 inner loops **run through the entire array for each number**, i.e it **overwrites the entire array with the latest prime.**

Fixes -

- 1d array is sufficient.
- No need of more than 1 loop, keep an index counter, starting at 0, and every time you find a prime, do `arr[index++] = prime`
- Or just use a list and insert in the end.

Answer (score 0):

try this.....

```
    int [][] array = new int [2][2];
    int N =10;
    for(int num = 2,i=0,j=0; num <= N; num++){
        if(isprime(num)){
            if(j >= array.length){
                j = 0;
                i++;
            }
            array[i][j++] = num;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
            System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```